# Merge two tables into one single view

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, union

I would like to merge two tables into one view.

Currently the first table contains 4 columns

```
ID | CatID | ImmID | Cost
```

The second one also 4 columns

```
ID | CatID | ImmID | Price
```

I would like to merge them so that the merged table will have 5 columns

```
ID | CatId | ImmId | Cost | Price
```

In case a catID is present in both table, I would like to have only one record
and if a catID is prensent in one of the two tables, I would like to put a 0 in Cost or Price column

So 3 cases.

This is my current query

```
SELECT first.CatID, first.ImmID, first.Cost, 0
FROM costs first
UNION
SELECT second.CatID, second.ImmID, 0, second.Price
FROM prices second
```

but it doesn't work because for one single catID, two records are returned

```
12| 15| 80| 1500 | 0 
12| 15| 80|    0 | 700
```

Instead of one which will look like

```
12| 15| 80| 1500| 700
```

Comment: Two records sorry for not mentionning it

Answer (score 0):

ok, try this now - This should do it:

```
--This query will return only one row if ID is common**
SELECT a.Id, a.CatId, a.ImmID, a.Cost, b.Price 
FROM first a, second b 
WHERE a.CatID=b.CatID 
  union
--this query will return only value from first table with price 0**
SELECT a.Id, a.CatId, a.ImmID, a.Cost, 0
FROM first a, second b 
WHERE a.CatID<>b.CatID
  union
--this query will return only value from second table with cost 0**
SELECT b.Id, b.CatId, b.ImmID, 0, b.Price 
FROM second b, first a
WHERE b.CatID<>a.CatID
```

Comment: it doesn't work since the CatIDs which are not in both tables are not displayed

Comment: instead of using a.Id=b.Id, u can use a.CatID=b.CatID. The idea suppose to be right.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do the trick ?

```
SELECT second.ID, first.CatID, first.ImmID, first.Cost, second.Price
FROM costs first , prices second
WHERE first.CatID = second.CatID
```

Comment: no because if a catId is not present on both tables, I want it to appear witch a 0 on Price (if it was only in the Cost table) or 0 on Cost (if it was only in the Price table)

Comment: hmm, not sure to understand your database design and your integrity constraints...